# Using SCP to copy a directory but can't access it in the location

Tags: ssh, scp

I have been trying to copy a directory using SCP from windows to my Ubuntu server.
it looks like it has completed the transfer on the windows CMD but when I use

```
ls
```

on the server in the location I copied it to, the directory I copied doesn't show up.

This is the command I am using on windows

```
scp -r C:\local\directory\ remoteUser@ip/remote/directory
```

this will show it's copying and say it as copied x files
but when I try access these on the remote server I cannot

The craziest thing is that when I revers the scp command like this:

```
scp -r remoteUser@ip/remote/directory C:\local\directory\
```

it will copy all the files back to the windows device from the remote server as if they were there all along

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Totally untested, so just a comment. `remoteUser@ip/remote/directory` does not contain a colon and therefore it's a *local* path; `remoteUser@ip:/remote/directory` would be a remote path. In Linux `scp` uses `cp` when copying from local to local, I don't know `scp` on Windows. Anyway, check the local path you *thought* was remote.

Comment: I do that all of the time!  `scp file user@host` creates a local file while `scp file user@host:` is what I want.

Comment: @Stewart [My solution to this problem](https://superuser.com/a/1747950/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no use on a source Windows platform, as described here

Comment: @roaima It's *my* solution and I don't use Windows. :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the person asking this question does

Comment: @roaima My comment with the link was addressed to Stewart who may use Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
scp C:\local\directory\* remoteUser@ip:/remote/directory/
```

What you're missing is the `:` (`[user@]host:[path]`) that separates the remote server path from the `SSH` line.

> The source and target may be specified as a local pathname, a remote host with optional path in the form `[user@]host:[path]`, or a URI in the form `scp://[user@]host[:port][/path]`.  Local file names can be made explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp treating file names containing ‘:’ as host specifiers.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the OP has created a directory ("folder") on their local Windows system called `remoteUser@ip`. And also that `scp` would have listed the copy source/destination, showing quite clearly that it's a local copy (`mkdir xx`, `echo boo > xx\boo.txt`, `scp -r xx ru@ip/r/d` results in output that includes `C:\Users\Roaima\Documents\xx\boo.txt -> C:\Users\Roaima\Documents\ru@ip\r\d\boo.txt`

Comment: Thank you, problem solved